# How to get current color from Linear Gradient?

Tags: android, colors, background, seekbar

I have an Seek Bar whose values ranges from 1 to 10. The THUMB stops at 1,2,3,4,5 ... 10.

The background color if SeekBar is Linear Gradient [Colors Start from RED, then YELLOW and lastly GREEN].  How to get the current color where thumb is positioned?

Comment: `ArgbEvaluator` is the only one that i can think of, but i'm not 100% if you get the exact same color

Answer (score 3):

[pskink's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460225/how-to-get-current-color-from-linear-gradient#comment54706585_33460225) is right. You can use an `ArgbEvaluator` to achieve this goal.

Let's assume this is your `SeekBar`:

```
 C1                                  C2                                  C3
 +-------|-------|-------|-------|---+---|-------|-------|-------|-------+                          
 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10
```

You've got 10 `Thumb` positions (numbers from `1` - `10`), 3 colors (`+` sign indicates the position of the color, and `C1`, `C2` and `C3` represent the name of the color).

The distance between `C1` and `C2` (as well as between `C2` and `C3`) can be devided into 9 pieces. Those 9 pieces can represent your `Thumb` positions:

```
 C1                                  C2                                  C3
 +-------|-------|-------|-------|---+---|-------|-------|-------|-------+ 
 |       |       |       |       |   |   |       |       |       |       |                    
0/9     2/9     4/9     6/9    8/9  9/9  |       |       |       |       |
                                     |   |       |       |       |       |
                                    0/9  1/9    3/9     5/9     7/9     9/9
```

Therefore the values of your `SeekBar` can be calculated this way:

```
int c1 = 0xFFFF0000; // ARGB representation of RED
int c2 = 0xFFFFFF00; // ARGB representation of YELLOW
int c3 = 0xFF00FF00; // ARGB representation of GREEN
ArgbEvaluator evaluator = new ArgbEvaluator();

int thumb1 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(0f,      c1, c2); // 0f/9f = 0f
int thumb2 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(2f / 9f, c1, c2);
int thumb3 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(4f / 9f, c1, c2);
int thumb4 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(6f / 9f, c1, c2);
int thumb5 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(8f / 9f, c1, c2);
int thumb6 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(1f / 9f, c2, c3);
int thumb7 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(3f / 9f, c2, c3);
int thumb8 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(5f / 9f, c2, c3);
int thumb9 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(7f / 9f, c2, c3);
int thumb10 = (int) evaluator.evaluate(1f,     c2, c3); // 9f/9f = 1f
```