# How to get the Color from LinearGradient?

Tags: xamarin.android, gradient, linear-gradients

I have used LinearGradient in my project. Please let us know, how to get the Color from the LinearGradient ?

**LinearGradient**

```
 LinearGradient gradient =  new LinearGradient(float x0, float y0, float x1, float y1, int[] colors, float[] positions, TileMode tile);
```

How to get the color from the gradient ?

Comment: Could you please tell me where you are using `LinearGradient` to get the color?

Comment: I am using this LinearGradient in applying a drawing area.

Comment: [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33460225/how-to-get-current-color-from-linear-gradient), could you elaborate it? Do you want to get the specific point's color?

Answer (score 0):

> Please let us know, how to get the Color from the LinearGradient ?

You can't. This is one way ticket, once the `LinearGradient` is created, you can't extract the colors for creating it.

If you want the colors, the only option is to locally store the colors for creating the `LinearGradient`.